# Expansion of continued fraction using recursion

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $f(n)$ be an arbitrary function such that $f(n)\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- Let $a(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $\frac{1}{G(0)}$ where
  $$
  G(j)=1-\frac{f(j)x}{G(j+1)}
  $$
  Here we have
  $$
  G(0)=1-\frac{f(0)x}{G(1)}=1-\frac{f(0)x}{1-\frac{f(1)x}{G(2)}}=1-\frac{f(0)x}{1-\frac{f(1)x}{1-\frac{f(2)x}{G(3)}}}
  $$
  and so on.
- Let
  $$
  \begin{split}
  R_1(n,q) & =\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q+1}f(j)R_1(n-1,j),\\
  R_1(0,q) & =[q=0]
  \end{split}
  $$
  Here square brackets denote Iverson brackets.

I conjecture that $$R_1(n,0)=a(n).$$

---

Moreover, let
$$
\begin{split}
R_2(n,q) &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q+1}f(j)R_2(n-1,j), \\
R_2(0,q) &= z^q.
\end{split}
$$
Is there a way to determine $[z^k]R_2(n,0)$ using continued fractions?

More generally, let $g(n)$ be an arbitrary function such that $g(n)\in\mathbb{N}$, and let
$$
\begin{split}
R_3(n,q) &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{g(q)}f(j)R_3(n-1,j), \\
R_3(0,q) &= z^q
\end{split}
$$
Is there a way to determine $[z^k]R_3(n,0)$ using continued fractions?

---

**UPD**: I think that the following observation can also be placed in this question:

- Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $A(x)$ where
  $$
  A(x)=1+\sum\limits_{n>0}f(n-1)(xA(x))^n
  $$
- Let
  $$
  \begin{split}
  R_4(n,q) & =R_4(n-1,q+1) + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}f(q-j)R_4(n-1,j),\\
  R_4(0,q) & =[q=0]
  \end{split}
  $$

I conjecture that $$R_4(n,0)=b(n).$$

See for example [A192206](https://oeis.org/A192206) and [A204218](https://oeis.org/A204218). Memorizing the values of $R_4(n,q)$ speeds up the calculation of these sequences.

---

Is there a way to prove it? Are there positive answers to questions related to continued fractions?

Comment: The update seems to have a tidier generalisation. Let $F$ be the ogf of $f$ and $A$ satisfy $A(x) = F(xA(x))$. Conjecture: $[x^n] A(x) = R_5(n,0)$ where $$R_5(n,q) = \begin{cases}[q=0]f_0 & \textrm{if } n = 0 \\ \sum_{j=0}^{q+1} f_0^{q-j} f_{q-j+1} R_5(n-1,j) & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Nice conjecture! Could you share how you came to this conclusion? Are there non-recursive methods to compute $A(x)$?

Comment: I started by rephrasing your update in terms of $A(x) = F(xA(x))$ with $f_0 = 1$, and then wondered whether the restriction could be removed. Trial and error with Sage, tweaking the recurrence for $R_4$, gave a version of $R_5$ which fits for low terms. I'm trying to prove a non-recursive expression for the coefficients of $A$ as sums over lattice points in a hyperplane: $$A(x) \stackrel?= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n+1} \sum_{\substack{v \in \mathbb{N}^{n+1},\\ \sum_i v_i = n}} \prod_i f_{j_i}$$