# Series reversion using something like continued fraction

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, continued-fractions

- Let $f(n)$ be an arbitrary function such that $f(n)\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- Let
  $$
  F(x)=\sum\limits_{m\geqslant 0}f(m)x^m
  $$
- Define the operator $\operatorname{SR}$, which is associated with the [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).
- Let $a(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $A(x)$ where
  $$
  A(x)=\frac{1}{x}\operatorname{SR}(xF(x))
  $$
- Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $\frac{1}{G(0)}$ where
  $$
  G(j)=F\left(\frac{x}{G(j+1)}\right)
  $$
  Here we have
  $$
  G(0)=F\left(\frac{x}{G(1)}\right)=F\left(\frac{x}{F\left(\frac{x}{G(2)}\right)}\right)=F\left(\frac{x}{F\left(\frac{x}{F\left(\frac{x}{G(3)}\right)}\right)}\right)
  $$
  and so on.

I conjecture that $$a(n)=b(n).$$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Please give a simple example of $f(n)$ and $a_n$ in your question to motivate it. Perhaps from the OEIS.

Comment: @Somos, I think the motivation is https://mathoverflow.net/q/449536/46140 and some discussion in the comments there (part of which has been deleted). Notamathematician, why not introduce $F$ as the generating function of $f$ and say $$A(x) = x^{-1} \operatorname{SR}(xF(x)) \\ G(j) = F(xG(j+1)^{-1})$$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am still waiting for a simple example of $\,f(n)\,$ and $\,a_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $F(0) \neq 0$, since otherwise we don't satisfy the assumptions for the series reversion. Let $G = G(0)$ be the fixpoint of the recurrence given:

$$G(x) = F\left(\frac{x}{G(x)}\right)$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{x}{G(x)}$:

$$x = \frac{x}{G(x)} F\left(\frac{x}{G(x)}\right)$$

By inspection of the structure we have $\frac{x}{G(x)} = \operatorname{SR}(xF(x))$, or $$\frac{1}{G(x)} = \frac{1}{x} \operatorname{SR}(xF(x))$$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Could you explain how you got the result after "by inspection of the structure"? What is the general rule here?

Comment: The definition of series reversion is that $h(\operatorname{SR}(h)(x)) = x$. The LHS is $x$ and the RHS has the form $g(x)F(g(x))$.

Comment: It means that we have $H(x)=xF(x), H(\operatorname{SR}(H(n)))=x=H(g(x)), \operatorname{SR}(H(n))=g(x)$, right?

Comment: Of course I mean $H(x)$ instead of $H(n)$.

Comment: $x=H(g(x)) \implies \operatorname{SR}(H(x))=g(x)$

Comment: How is it so obvious to you?

Comment: It wasn't, but I only post the clean route to the solution rather than the dead ends I tried.